# The divs dont shift their positions with decreasing screen size

Tags: css, media-queries

I need to position footer1 and  footer2 with abolute position with 20px from left side using media query.But no matter what I do the 2 divs dont move at all.Please help

```
  @media only screen and (max-width:1232px) {

    .footer1{

    left:20px;

    }

    .footer2{

    left:20px;

    }
```

}

```
  <div class="color2">
    <div class="footer1" style="color:white;position:absolute ;top:0px;             left:20px ;font-family: 'Abel',sans-serif;">
    <ul style="list-style:none; "><li style="font-size:20px; font-  weight:bold">Contact Us</li>
            <li style="font-size:15px"> </li>
            <li style="font-size:15px">No. 461, </li>
            <li style="font-size:15px">Rose Road</li>
            <li style="font-size:15px">Bk Avenue</li>
            <li style="font-size:15px">Sri- Lanka</li>
            <li style="font-size:15px">07786755422</li></ul>

     </div>


     <div class="i_info" style="font-size:30px ; position:absolute ; top : 310px">
       <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">  <i class="fab fa-facebook-square icon-7x" STYLE="color:white ; position:absolute ;left:1000px"></i></a>
       <a href="https://twitter.com/login" target="_blank">  <i class="fab fa-twitter-square" STYLE="color:white ; position:absolute ; left:1080px"></i></a>
       <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login" target="_blank">   <i class="fab fa-linkedin" STYLE="color:white ; position:absolute ;left:1160px"></i></a>

       </div>


       <div class = "footer2" style="width:600px;height:20px;font-size:16px ;color:white ; position:absolute;top:360px ;left:978px ;font-family: 'Abel',sans-serif;" >
        <i class="far fa-copyright"></i>
        BT Solutions

       </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inline styles will always take priority over the ones declared in your CSS file (unless you force them with !important, but that's a completely different story). As long as you use the `left:978px` on your second div, it won't move even if you try to use media queries.

In general, the priority would be:

1. styles declared with !important,
2. inline-styles declared on the element
3. styles for a combined selector
4. styles for a generic selector

Also, I really recommend you don't use inline css, but put it all in the file instead - it is very rare you need to use the inline styles anyways and that way you're not able to share the properties between elements with the same class.

You should just use

```
.footer1 {
    color:white;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:20px;
    font-family: 'Abel',sans-serif;
}

.footer1 ul {
    list-style:none;
}

...
```

etc. and then use your max-width media queries in the bottom (also in the right order, so first the highest max-width, followed by queries addressing lower width).

Comment: Thank you so much . You solved my problem . I wasted hours on this. I removed the inline style as you said and put them in the css file. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I suggest remove all inline styles and put them to separet file.

```
<div class="footer2">
```

css file

```
.footer2 {
  width:600px; // for me is terrible to use magic numbers to width and height of element.
  height:20px;
  font-size:16px;
  color:white;
  position:absolute; // is really needed to change position?
  top:360px; // very bad practice
  left:978px; // very, very bad way to set left space, maybe you can center this 
  font-family: 'Abel',sans-serif; 
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1232px) { // why this value in breakpoint?

  .footer2 {
    left:20px;
  }
}
```

and this should work.

I added some comments, because you want achieve your goal in bad way.

Comment: I am still a beginner . But thank you so much for the valuable input.

Comment: how do I center footer2 ,sir?

Comment: There is a many possible ways, easy one is use flex. Add to footer element display: flex, justify-content: center, align-items: center - this centers content both vertically and horizontally.

Comment: footer2 disappears when I use display: flex, justify-content: center, align-items: center